# Fetch images which are stored in filestore odoo 11

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

How can I Fetch images which are stored in file-store odoo-11?

I am trying to fetch the **product.template** image, which is stored in **ir_attachment** in the format `39/39abfeca081b17a6b93fbeaeead3e34025a39f9c`.

This is not a binary code. I tried this code in [this URL](https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter). It didn't give any image. Later, I understood that this is a code in file store. When we download a Database in zip format and extract the DB we will see the file-store inside this folder "39" is a folder name and `39abfeca081b17a6b93fbeaeead3e34025a39f9c` is an image name.

My Requirement is Product Image will be fetched from another Application. How can I store this in database with binary code so that other applications will fetch that binary code and get the image?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

The stored files in Odoo filestores are regular files, which can be opened by the OS programs and can be read by any other Application as bytes of data like any other file in your computer. If you wanna get the value of the file stored in base64 format you could build the url for that file by having the id of the stored attachment and make a call to the Odoo instance and get the file content in base64.

The url format is like:
http://example.com/web/content/5

Where the id of the attachment is 5 at the end of the url